# Swift unwanted URL percent encoding

Tags: swift, urlencode

I'm trying to format a URL for use in accessing an API. The documentation for the api specifies a URL that contains the "[" and "]" characters in it. When I create a URL from my string in Swift, it is adding percent encoding and changing these characters to "%5B" and "%5D".

How do I tell swift to not percent encode these characters? Thanks!

```
func attemptPubgIDLookup (playerName: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
let region = "pc-na"
let urlString = "https://api.playbattlegrounds.com/shards/" + region + "/players?filter[playerNames]=" + playerName
let finalUrl = URL(string:urlString)
if let finalUrl = finalUrl {

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: finalUrl)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.get.rawValue

    urlRequest.addValue(pubgApiKey, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization: Bearer")
    urlRequest.addValue("application/vnd.api+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    Alamofire.request(urlRequest)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            debugPrint(response)
        })
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you want.  When the server receives your request it will decode the URL...

> %5B is '[' and %5D is ']'

This is called [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and is used in encoding special characters in the url parameter values.

Comment: Hmm. I guess my issue lies elsewhere. Their documentation seemed pretty specific about it, but you're probably right. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried calling the url directly.  Placing it in the browser and calling it?

Comment: I'd like to, but as you can see above the API call requires an authorization header. I don't suppose there is any way to add that into the url?

Comment: You can.  There are tools out there that let you construct a URL like PostMan, but maybe someone will suggest something simpler than going through the trouble.  Postman url: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization

Comment: Oh wow. I have postman already and I formed the request. It worked! So my issue is me not knowing how to properly form the headers in swift.... nuts.